# How to subset labels to a ggplot graph without printing Aesthetics error?

Tags: r, ggplot2, error-handling, geom-text, aesthetics

This line of code is not working. The problem is when I add this geom_text line that is meant to filter out certain points of the data and label them.

This is the code:

```
ggplot(data=bg_total_df, aes(x = bg_total_num, y = bg_total$bloodGlucose)) +
  geom_text(data = subset(bg_total, bloodGlucose < 78), label = bg_total$bloodGlucose)+
geom_point(color = ifelse(bg_total$bloodGlucose < 78, "red", "blue"))
```

> Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data
>   (16): x, y

The `ggplot + geom_point` code work together just fine. It's when the geom_text code is added where I get this error.

I have been trying to fix this geom_text set of code so that the outliers of the graph (`bloodGlucose` is less than 78 and greater than 271) will be red and labeled with their number amount. The code that I have written is my first attempt at doing this by starting with the values less than 78.

Here is the code to set up the df.

```
bg_total <- filter(csutrauma.data, bloodGlucose >= 0)
bg_total_num <- 1:328

bg_total_df <- data.frame(bg_total_num, bg_total$bloodGlucose)

bg_total$bloodGlucose (these are the filtered out blood glucose data) <-  c(118.0,  72.0, 207.0, 107.0,  99.0, 106.0,  98.0,  89.0, 114.0,  98.0, 109.0, 114.0,  85.0, 138.0, 100.0, 118.0,  99.0, 104.0,  80.0, 105.0, 113.0,  89.0, 116.0, 121.0, 120.0, 109.0,  97.0, 100.0, 112.0, 133.0,  95.0, 107.0,  91.0, 133.0,  80.0, 114.0, 118.0, 109.0, 111.0, 115.0, 122.0,  90.0, 114.0,  93.0, 106.0, 555.0, 106.0, 106.0, 119.0,  95.0, 153.0, 118.0,  75.0, 112.0, 102.0, 103.0, 150.0, 109.0, 110.0, 206.0, 103.0, 266.0, 103.0, 104.0, 119.0, 106.0,  94.0, 94.0, 119.0, 120.0, 96.0, 252.0, 121.0, 126.0, 317.0, 170.0, 119.0,  98.0, 124.0, 137.0, 255.0, 136.0, 126.0, 0.0, 117.0, 134.0, 133.0, 102.0, 150.0, 232.0, 132.0, 112.0, 78.0, 155.0, 113.0, 122.0, 153.0,  96.0,  83.0, 154.0,  41.0,  91.0, 120.0, 134.0, 126.0, 168.0, 196.0, 125.0, 105.0, 105.0,  93.0, 88.0,  89.0,  93.0, 120.0,  93.0,  93.0, 135.0, 102.0,  86.0,  93.0, 141.0, 150.0,  96.0, 101.0,  61.0, 110.0,  81.0,  97.0, 140.0,  95.0, 106.0, 117.0, 119.0, 139.0, 110.0, 101.0, 128.0, 107.0, 160.0, 122.0, 135.0,  59.0, 102.0,  72.0, 145.0, 104.0, 134.0, 113.0, 105.0, 107.0, 100.0,  65.0, 100.0, 136.0, 110.0, 159.0, 107.0, 115.0, 101.0, 493.0,  78.0,  84.0, 229.0, 102.0, 172.0, 139.0, 102.0, 541.0,  94.0,  91.0,  88.0, 181.0, 129.0, 123.0, 108.0, 115.0,  97.0, 159.0, 124.0, 118.0, 138.0, 182.0, 115.0, 119.0, 101.0,  99.0,  88.0, 134.0, 104.0, 152.0, 130.0,  90.0, 100.0, 157.0, 112.0, 120.0, 110.0, 112.0, 104.0,  71.0, 120.0, 254.0, 118.0, 119.0, 94.0, 104.0, 183.0, 227.0, 210.0, 150.0,  93.0,  91.0,  99.0,  86.0,  90.0, 115.0, 247.0, 111.0, 109.0, 90.0, 113.0, 98.0, 80.0, 145.0, 101.0,  94.0,  94.0, 138.0, 241.0,   3.8, 106.0,  93.0, 96.0, 105.0, 181.0,  95.0,  82.0,  82.0,  18.0, 148.0, 175.0, 323.0, 118.0,  89.0, 100.0, 117.0, 175.0, 200.0, 147.0, 108.0, 210.0, 123.0, 136.0, 107.0, 117.0, 116.0, 154.0,  56.0, 102.0, 105.0, 100.0, 108.0, 226.0, 149.0, 86.0, 116.0, 140.0, 133.0, 121.0, 122.0,  98.0,  95.0, 118.0, 114.0, 113.0, 94.0,  70.0,  52.0, 110.0, 189.0,  82.0 200.0,  89.0,  95.0,  93.0, 111.0, 117.0, 110.0, 156.0,  87.0, 136.0, 336.0, 112.0, 128.0,  92.0, 61.0, 130.0, 119.0, 152.0,  90.0, 111.0, 116.0, 133.0,  94.0, 326.0, 121.0, 119.0 121.0 152.0, 113.0, 128.0, 123.0, 155.0, 176.0, 101.0, 248.0,  64.0, 90.0, 105.0, 235.0, 124.0, 142.0, 388.0, 118.0, 202.0, 156.0, 195.0)
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You are trying to map aesthetics to data but you are not putting it inside an `aes` call. Try something like `geom_text(aes(label = bloodGlucose), data = subset(bg_total, bloodGlucose < 78))`

Comment: And never use `data$column` inside `aes()`. Just use the column name. [See this answer for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51194689/903061)

Comment: I tried the code you have mentioned - it is still printing out the same error. The bg_total$bloodGlucose column has 328 rows. Whereas the subset has 16 points - I am not sure if it has to do with this, but I've seen other examples where the subsetting works in their case. I have been trying all kinds of edits, but with the same error every time.

Comment: Maybe you can add to your post the edits you've made that other commenters suggested. More crucially, you haven't [posted any data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), which makes it difficult for folks to provide much more than guesses as to what's going on

Comment: Sorry about that. I just updated the post to show the code to set up the df, as well as the data I'm using.

Comment: your code to produce your dataframe is not reproducible like that - please rearrange. It is also good practice to try one's code in an *empty* R session. Also, reduce your problem to the minimum, and thus your code. You very likely do not need 328 rows to reproduce your problem.

Comment: It's 328 rows out of an excel sheet with 80 columns. I just wrote it this way because I don't know how to make a dataframe for ggplot without using 1:328 as the rows. Please let me know how I can fix this if possible.

Comment: I suggest to read the top answer at this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Have you worked with `ggplot` before? I think you would benefit from just working your way through some tutorials and then revisiting this. [R Graphics Cookbook](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/) is a great place to start