# Problem with ggplot when reassigning variables for data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I noticed a strange behavior with `ggplot`. I want to create multiple figures one after another, while reassigning data variables in between. The problem is that `ggplot` uses the new value for the previously saved graphs.

Here is a simple example of the behavior, but keep in mind that this is part of a larger workflow, where I create multiple plots and join them at the end with `grid.arrange`.

```
resp <- iris$Sepal.Length
p <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Petal.Length, y = resp))+
    geom_point()
p
```

This is the normal plot:

[image: normal plot]

Now I reassign `resp`, but I would expect `p` not to change. However, it does!

```
resp <- iris$Sepal.Width
p
```

THis is the changed plot:

[image: changed plot]

**As you can see, `p` now uses `iris$Sepal.Width` for y, which is not the desired behavior. Why is that, and how can I make this work the way I want?**

Interestingly, it works fine when the plotting is in a function. Still, I would like a solution without this workaround.

```
irisplot <- function(resp){
  panel <- ggplot(iris, aes(Petal.Length, resp))+
    geom_point()
  return(panel)
}

q1 <- irisplot(iris$Sepal.Length)
q2 <- irisplot(iris$Sepal.Width)

q1 #as expected
```

Also, I read that it might be bad practice to use vectors in aes() (e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51194498/r-ggplot2-difference-between-ggplotdata-aesx-variable-and-ggplotdat) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32543340/issue-when-passing-variable-with-dollar-sign-notation-to-aes-in-combinatio)), so I am also open to solutions that address that.

Comment: it might be better if resp was a new column in your dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ggplot2 saves the data.frame passed to the `data` parameter in the ggplot object. For anything referenced in `aes` that is not in this data.frame it has to rely on scoping to find it when the plot is build (each time it is printed).

So, just make sure that `resp` is passed to the `data` parameter, too.

```
resp <- iris$Sepal.Length
p <- ggplot(cbind(iris, resp), aes(x = Petal.Length, y = resp))+
  geom_point()
p

resp <- iris$Sepal.Width
p
#same plot
```

PS: Your example with the function works, because the plot environment of `q1` and `q2` are environments created during the function call whereas the plot environment of `p` is the global environment. Compare `p$plot_env` and `q1$plot_env` and check out `ls(q1$plot_env)`.